# Custom barTintColor for navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to get a customized color for my apps navigation bar and it's not coming up right. The hex code for the exact color I need to use is the blue #023883. I looked up the rbg percentages from this site: http://www.colorhexa.com/023883 and the percentages are: rgb(0.8%,22%,51.4%). I put it inside my code like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor 
colorWithRed:0.8 green:22 blue:51.4 alpha:1.0]; 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = 
@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor]}; 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor 
whiteColor]; 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

I also tried to implement code that enables the use of inputting hexcode for the color value but that didn't work either. Is there another way for me to be able to achieve this color? (I also tried to put only blue at 100 and it still wasnt dark enough a color)

Comment: r u using Storyboard

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard

Comment: I give the Upvote , have a nice day , I also face the issue in starting , Now only in my answer easily optimize the coding and time also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget % ,it should be

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor
                                                        colorWithRed:0.008 green:0.22 blue:0.514 alpha:1.0];
```

[image]

**Edit,about how to make statusBar white**

1. set this key to NO in **info.plist** file `View controller-based status bar appearance`.Click the `plus` icon in the right of **Information Property List**,then you click a `V` in the new row,it will auto complete,the first one is this key
   [image]
2. In app delegate

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
   return YES;
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: Any idea on how I can change the status bar to white?

Comment: I can't seem to find the "View controller-based status bar appearance" in either of the two .plist files my project has

Comment: See the update image.You need to add a new key-value

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**

Select your `NavigationController`

**Step - 2**

selet the `Navigation bar`

[image]

**Step-3**

you can get the Navigation bar attributes

[image]

**Step -4** in Here you can change `Title` , `Font`, `Background color` , etc.

[image]

**statusBar - Transparent**

`Target` --> `Genral` --> U get the following result change `Status Bar Style` --> `Light` , please follow the image.

don't forget to set `NO` in `plist`  String Name is --> `View controller-based status bar appearance`

[image]

Comment: its affected in all View controllers what ever you added in your navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

You are using `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` wrong.
You are supposed to enter percentages (0.8, 22 and 51.4 in your case), but are entering them in a wrong manner.

Please enter 0.008, 0.22 and 0.514 instead:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.008 green:0.22 blue:0.514 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Any idea on how I can change the status bar to white?

Comment: By setting the `barTintColor` to white (navigationBar). Edit: misread your question, please see the answer from @Leo.

Comment: Thanks again! (I dont have enough points to give you an upvote but im 2 away and will do so when I get it!)